# How to view nginx logs with stdout set

Tags: nginx, stdout

On my nginx config file I have the following:

```
access_log /dev/stdout main_timed;
error_log /dev/stderr notice;
```

Not sure what this does but my question is how would I view these log files?

Thanks

Comment: you can specify the actual log path and log levels to persist and view log files -- more can be read here https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/monitoring/logging/ and for configuring log rotation for large contents overperiod of time: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-logging-and-log-rotation-in-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-vps - the above would be sending the log message to standard streams and should be available on console/terminal

Comment: Ah ok, so no way read a file then.

Comment: The log path specified is for file only

Comment: Sorry, not sure what that means